# Consolidating answers? What's the best practice?

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9887/tradeoff-bounds-for-halfspace-range-counting/9893#9893) I posted an answer, which points to a survey paper which could answer his question, but I didn't have the time or expertise to fully answer the question myself. Later, another user posted another, more authoritative answer which more directly addresses the question and also points to the same survey.

I'm wondering, should the two answers be consolidated in any way, or should I edit my answer to point to the second answer? The reason that I ask is that now that the second answer has been posted, mine somewhat redundant. The only additional information it adds is which sections of the referenced papers are relevant to the question.

In general, what's the best practice when partially overlapping answers are posted?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anything in particular needs to be done. Your answer, while possibly subsumed by the other one, was provided independently.